# pytest' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: pytest

I just started learning  python selenium concepts.
I installed pytest 7.2.1 latest version. and while checking whether installed or not iam getting below error.
Could you please assist.
'pytest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

for practice purpose i tried.

Answer (score 1):

First install pytest (if its already installed then ignore this):

```bash
$ python3 -m pip install pytest
```

Then do this:

```bash
~/yourproject $ python -m pytest <arguments>
```

Tested on Python 3.10.10 and Windows 10.

Comment: I tried to use 1st option got error like  source code string cannot contain null bytes

Comment: @Anusha Maybe your index.py file contains null bytes? Please check your code.

Comment: @Anusha Remove null bytes (\x00 in unicode) in your code